shell script arguments not getting passed in
Folder Structure
geoloc-util.sh
tests
  |- test_geoloc_util.bats

from root, I'm able to run the command and the output is as expected
./geoloc-util.sh "Madison, WI" "94552"
./geoloc-util.sh -l "Madison, WI" "94552"
./geoloc-util.sh --location "Madison, WI" "94552"

The problem I'm having is in the bats file
@test "Valid city and state" {
  ../geoloc-util.sh --locations "Madison, WI"
  [ "$status" -eq 0 ]
  [[ "$output" == *"Location: Madison, WI, US"* ]]
  [[ "$output" == *"Latitude:"* ]]
  [[ "$output" == *"Longitude:"* ]]
}

For some reason the execution line of ../geoloc-util.sh --locations "Madison, WI"
the 2 arguments are not being passed in.  When putting debug code of echo "$@" at the top of the .sh file, it just outputs the file path.
I've tried run, also run bash. Tried to find what documentation I could and I can't figure out why those arguments aren't getting passed in.
expect the bats file test calls to behave the same as invoking the execution on cli

If you can find documentation for your bats-core see if they offer a debugging mode/flag. Else Add set -x as the 2nd line of your .sh file and look at the trace generated. You'll see the original text/code of the cmd, and then a 2nd line preceded by +. All $vars (or $1, $2, ..), will be replaced with the actual values so you can see the exact text of the command that was executed by the shell. But really, this seems to be a .bats-core issue and you should try to find the git-hub, or where ever the developers keep the bug list and help users. Good luck.

@B12 Out of curiosity, is there a specific reason you are using bracket style tests ([[  and ]]) instead of assert_output ?


expect the bats file test calls to behave the same as invoking the execution on cli

They do... So there is something in the machine messing things up.
It looks like some important detail is missing from your question's example.
I have same directory setup:
.
├── geoloc-util.sh
└── tests
    └── test_geoloc_util.bats

I have created a naive implementation of the geoloc-util, that also output the parameters it receives, using ${@}:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat <<TXT
    Parameters: ${@}
    Location: Madison, WI, US
    Latitude:  43°04′29″N
    Longitude: 89°23′03″W
TXT

And I have the following test:
#!/usr/bin/env bats

@test "can run our script" {
    bash ./geoloc-util.sh --locations "Madison, WI"
}

@test "Valid parameters" {
    output="$(bash ./geoloc-util.sh --locations "Madison, WI")"

    [[ "$output" == *'Parameters: --locations'* ]]
}

@test "Valid city and state" {
  run bash ./geoloc-util.sh --locations "Madison, WI"

  [ "$status" -eq 0 ]

  [[ "$output" == *"Location: Madison, WI, US"* ]]
  [[ "$output" == *"Latitude:"* ]]
  [[ "$output" == *"Longitude:"* ]]
}

If I run this (from the root of the project) using:
bats /code/tests --show-output-of-passing-tests

Or if you prefer docker:
docker run -it -v "$PWD:/code" bats/bats:latest --show-output-of-passing-tests /code/tests

Then I get the expected output:
test_geoloc_util.bats
 ✓ can run our script
       Parameters: --locations Madison, WI
       Location: Madison, WI, US
       Latitude:  43°04′29″N
       Longitude: 89°23′03″W
 ✓ Valid parameters
 ✓ Valid city and state

Some things to note:

My geoloc-util.sh is not executable, so it has to be run using bash geoloc-util.sh or run bash geoloc-util.sh
As I run bats from the project root, the path to geoloc-util.sh is ./geoloc-util.sh not ../geoloc-util.sh
As you can see, --show-output-of-passing-tests shows output, but only if it is not swallowed by a sub-shell or by run. There are also --print-output-on-failure and --verbose-run that are worth looking into or (for more complex tests) --gather-test-outputs-in
If run bash ... is not used, $output and $status are not filled, meaning you will have to grab them yourself. Hence the subshell in the "Valid parameters" test.

